# Filtering properties from yaml file

Tags: java, spring, java-8, java-stream, swagger

I have this yaml file which is mapped to class T1 .

```
T1:
  apis :
    - api: r1
      cnfig :
        - country: M1
          usersegment: 5|6|10
        - country: M2
          usersegment: 10|11
     - api: r2
      cnfig :
        - country: M1
          usersegment: 5|6|10|11
        - country: M2
          usersegment: 10|11
```

I need to fine all apis where `usersegment` is `5` for country `M1` . So for the above input i should get `r1` and `r2` both with complete config details . And for `usersegment` `11` and country `M1` i should get only `r2`.

I tried doing the same using stream in java :

```
masterConfig.getConfig("tv").getApis()
    .stream()
    .filter(api -> api.Configs().stream()
        .filter(singleConfig -> singleConfig.usersegment.contains("5") && 
            country.equals("M1"))
        .count() > 0)
    .count()
```

Everytime it is showing the same count which is `2` . i need to get the list of all apis that has country : `M1` and `usersegment` `5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following snippet :

```
        List<Api> collect = apis
                .stream().filter(
                        api -> (api.getConfigs().stream()
                                .filter(singleConfig -> singleConfig.usersegment.contains("11")
                                        && singleConfig.country.equals("M1"))
                                .count() > 0))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(Note that I've created custom objects to simulate the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Better use [`Stream::anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) as a return value of the `Predicate` within the filter method. The advantage of this **short-circuiting** method is the stream stops iterating over the elements once a first element is found qualified and `true` is returned.

```
List<Api> apiList = apis
    .stream()
    .filter(api -> api.getConfigs().stream()
            .anyMatch(
                singleConfig -> singleConfig.usersegment.contains("11") && 
                singleConfig.country.equals("M1")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Moreover, `singleConfig.country.equals("M1")` shall be used.